# Custom routes with GET Params : HTTP RESPONSE 302 ; how to get GET params values?

Tags: magento2, router

> etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="example" frontName="ex">
            <module name="Company_Package" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Package\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    public function execute() {
        //get GET Params
    }

}
```

If I access to

```
mywebsite.com/ex
```

I have the correct page.

If I access to

```
mywebsite.com/ex?somethinggreat=1
```

I have a 302

How to **get the value of "somethinggreat"**, and get a HTTP RESPONSE of **200** ?

(The solution might be in the controller's dockblock, or in the routes.xml file, but I can't find out exactly how.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
<?php
namespace Company\Package\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $this->request->getParam('somethinggreat');
    }

}
```